# Using the Joomla Extension manager to support component add ons

Tags: component, development

Is there some sort of API available to trigger an install through the extension manager?

The reason I ask this is allowing a component to install add ons though its administration is handy, but it should of course keep to the Joomla API's to ensure the updater can read it.

So far I have been unable to find documentation on such a thing.

My idea for what I am building is to load an xml file that links to the typical update manifests used by Joomla, to list all extensions that can be used to add on to my component. This can give me a link to the install zip. Having that I can pass it to the extension manager to auto-install it (then redirect back).

UPDATE: Just to clarify, this would install the extension through the component, not during install of the component. Although they can end up with similar code, I feel integrating a component into the extension manager in some form is really useful when it comes to supporting add ons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good example of a complex installation script that can be fired from scriptfile tag ([http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Developing_a_MVC_Component/Adding_an_install-uninstall-update_script_file](http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5%3aDeveloping_a_MVC_Component/Adding_an_install-uninstall-update_script_file)).

https://github.com/akeeba/fof/blob/development/fof/utils/installscript/installscript.php

Most actions to install libraries, plugins, modules, etc are based on **JInstaller**.

Comment: Although I feel this could lead to it, it is not installing them during installation, but through the component itself. I will dig around based on this information though, thank you.

Comment: Your component could provide a separate UI for management, but if your add on extensions are following the same standards, you can use the JInstaller API.